# This vs Class name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm using a code snippet from someone else and I can't seem to understand when he's using **this** and when he's using the **name of the class**

On line 3 he uses **this.pusher**, while in the $.each function he's using **chat.pusher** ( the name of the current object )

```
connect : function ( )
{
    if ( typeof Pusher !== 'undefined' )
    {

        this.pusher = new Pusher( config.pusher_app_key , { encrypted : true, authEndpoint : '/chat.php' , auth : { params : { hash : app.session.get(), mobile : app.mobile } } } );

        $.each( chat.channels , function ( channel_type , channel_name ) {

            chat.pusher.subscribe( channel_name );

            if ( chat.events[ channel_type ] )
                $.each( chat.events[ channel_type ] , function ( event_name , callback ) {
                    chat.pusher.channels.channels[ channel_name ].bind( event_name , chat.events[ channel_type ][ event_name ] );
                });

        });
},
```

I also added a screenshot which shows a clear overview of the situation.

[image]

Comment: Inside `$.each`, `this` refers to the current item. `This` confusion is one of the reasons many developers start most of their functions by storing `this` in `that` or `self` like `var self = this;`.

Comment: ref [docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: If he used "this" inside $.each, he would reference each chat channel, but he wants to reference the chat instance

Comment: just an unhappy codding, usually this is used inside an complex object with methods.

Comment: `this` in the context of `this.pusher = ...` refers to the `chat` object. Whereas `this` in the `$.each` loop would refer to the `channel_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in `$.each`, `this` refers to the currently iterated element (in this case, `this` would **not** have referred to the current `chat` object.)

He used `chat` in that case instead of several options (such as using `Function.prototype.bind`, or the common `var _this = this`.

Example:

```
$.each(['a', 'b'], function(el) {
    console.log(this); // iteration 1: 'a', iteration 2: 'b'
});
```

Another example:

```
var canInTheHat = {
    someMethod: function() {
        console.log(this); // => catInTheHat

        $.each(['a', 'b'], function() {
            console.log(this); // => iteration 1: 'a', iteration 2: 'b'
        });
    },
    someOtherMethod: function() {
        console.log(this); // => catInTheHat

        $.each(['a', 'b'], function() {
            console.log(this); // => iteration 1: catInTheHat, iteration 2: catInTheHat
        }.bind(this)); // notice the bind
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chat.pusher.subscribe( channel_name );
```

is inside a function:

```
$.each( chat.channels , function ( channel_type , channel_name ) {
    chat.pusher.subscribe( channel_name );
        ...
});
```

Inside that function, the `this` keyword does not point to the `chat` object. So usually you'd do this:

```
var self = this;
$.each( chat.channels , function ( channel_type , channel_name ) {
    self.pusher.subscribe( channel_name );
        ...
});
```

But here, `chat` is a global, singular object, so it was used instead.

Comment: is it better to use 'chat' or the 'self'? thank you!

Comment: Here, there's no difference (except, perhaps, to the readability of your code). But if chat was not a global object, but a class (or function in JavaScript) instead, you couldn't use it and would have to create a self variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside a [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function is bound to the current item.

He should have used it like this

```
$.each( chat.events[ channel_type ] , function ( event_name , callback ) {
    chat.pusher.channels.channels[ channel_name ].bind( event_name , this );
});
```

instead of using the notation `chat.events[ channel_type ][ event_name ]`

Now it makes sense to use `chat` inside this function.

Btw `chat` is not a class name, but the name of the variable that contains the object, as it's not a function.

Comment: I don't understand how 'this' can replace chat.events[ channel_type ][ event_name ] in this case? Thank you!

Comment: as it's iterating over `chat.events[ channel_type ]` and use the key `event_name ` -> `chat.events[ channel_type ][ event_name ]` is `this`

Answer (score 0):

If he used `this` inside `$.each`, he would reference each chat channel, but he wants to reference the chat instance itself.